# XPATH - select range of nodes

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following code:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <p>don't select me</p>
    <p>select me 1</p>
    <p>select me 2</p>
    <p>select me 3</p>
    <p>don't select me</p>
</div>
```

I need to select p[2] through p[4].

Tried with this code and it didn't work:

```
'.//*[@id="mydiv"]/p[preceding-sibling::p[4] and following-sibling::p[2]]'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try:

```
'//*[@id='mydiv']/p[position()>1 and position()<5]'
```

Or, your initial code can be changed to:

```
'//*[@id="mydiv"]/p[preceding-sibling::p and following-sibling::p]'
```

So that all of the `p` with preceding and following `p` nodes will be selected (i.e. p[2] through p[4]).

Comment: if there is other tags like <h3> in the middle of the <p>, will the <h3> content be included if i use '//*[@id="mydiv"]/p[preceding-sibling::p and following-sibling::p]' ?

Comment: @Michimcchicken, no. It should be changed to '//*[@id="mydiv"]/*[preceding-sibling::p and following-sibling::p]' in order to select any nodes inside

Answer (score 1):

XPATH can be written in below format too:-

```
//p[position()>1 and position()<5]
```

**OR**

```
//p[position()>=2 and position()<=4]
```

### Result:

```
select me 1
select me 2
select me 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps you need to use this, if max number of «p» greater than 5:**

`//p[(position() idiv 2) eq 1]` --- to select ODD nodes(based on position number)

`//p[(position() idiv 2) eq 0]` --- to select EVEN nodes(based on position number)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `mod` instead of `idiv`.